# Camera will not follow player on positive x, y coordinates but will on negative x, y coordinates. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Camera will not follow player on positive x, y coordinates but will on negative x, y coordinates. What did I do wrong? I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8YUfee_pzc&t=3612s and it looks like I copied it to the letter but I can't get it to work. (Code starts at 55:39 in the video)

```
public Transform lookAt;
public float boundX = 0.15f;
public float boundY = 0.05f;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 delta = Vector3.zero;

    // This is to check if we're inside the bounds on the X axis

    float deltaX = lookAt.position.x - transform.position.x;
    if (deltaX > boundX || deltaX < -boundX)
    {
        if (transform.position.x < lookAt.position.x)
        {
            deltaX = deltaX - boundX;
        }
        else
        {
            delta.x = deltaX + boundX;
        }
    }

    // This is to check if we're inside the bounds on the Y axis

    float deltaY = lookAt.position.y - transform.position.y;
    if (deltaY > boundY || deltaY < -boundY)
    {
        if (transform.position.y < lookAt.position.y)
        {
            deltaY = deltaY - boundY;
        }
        else
        {
            delta.y = deltaY + boundY;
        }
    }

    transform.position += new Vector3(delta.x, delta.y, 0);
}
```

}`

Comment: Well one thing that does come to mind is you find a difference. If the difference is say -5,-5 you then subtract it eg add 5 to both not  add the difference because you test if it’s > or <

Comment: Write an `isValueInRange` function and unit test it.  Then use it to write an `isPointInRectangle` function and unit test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial (and/or) you has some typos/mistakes there.

In the two cases

```
if (transform.position.x < lookAt.position.x)
{
    deltaX = deltaX - boundX;
}
else
{
    delta.x = deltaX + boundX;
}
```

you are changing two different values. Once `deltaX` and once `delta.x`.

Later in the tutorial he made another mistake and uses

```
transform.position += new Vector3(delta.x, deltaY);
```

so again once using the `delta.x` but the other time the `deltaY` which is unrelated to `delta.y`.

I suppose it should rather be

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    var delta = Vector3.zero;

    // This is to check if we're inside the bounds on the X axis
    var deltaX = lookAt.position.x - transform.position.x;
    if (deltaX > boundX || deltaX < -boundX)
    {
        if (transform.position.x < lookAt.position.x)
        {
            delta.x = deltaX - boundX;
        }
        else
        {
            delta.x = deltaX + boundX;
        }
    }

    // This is to check if we're inside the bounds on the Y axis
    var deltaY = lookAt.position.y - transform.position.y;
    if (deltaY > boundY || deltaY < -boundY)
    {
        if (transform.position.y < lookAt.position.y)
        {
            delta.y = deltaY - boundY;
        }
        else
        {
            delta.y = deltaY + boundY;
        }
    }

    transform.position += delta;
}
```

probably could also simplify it a bit using e.g.

```
Vector2 delta = lookAt.position - transform.position;

if (Mathf.Abs(delta.x) > boundX)
{
    delta.x += boundX * Mathf.Sign(delta.x);
}

if (Mathf.Abs(delta.y) > boundY)
{
    delta.y += boundY * Mathf.Sign(delta.y);
}

transform.position += (Vector3) delta;
```

but not sure on that last bit since typing on the phone here ;)

Comment: That was it! The first typo was definitely me. Thanks so much! @derHugo

Comment: @ColdCosmicSoup You're welcome! Also checkout the bottom .. not tested since on phone right now and my brain is already tired ^^ but I think you could simplify this a lot further

Comment: I would paste the code here but I can't get the back ticks to work. I get an error saying "Assets\Scripts\CameraMotor.cs(26,9): error CS0034: Operator '+=' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2' " I don't know much code at all but when I learn more I'll definitely try to simplify!  Thanks again : ) @derHugo